# Can't Get .Net Web Service to Return Json

Tags: jquery, .net, json, web-services

I've read the posts here and followed to the best of my knowledge, but still cannot get my web service to return json.

The web service, .Net 4.0

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment     the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class JsonWS : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string Sum()
{
    string x = "1", y = "2";
    return x + y;
}
```

}

and here's my jquery call.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#btn_test').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "http://localhost/jsontest/JsonWS.asmx/Sum",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (json) {
                alert(json.d);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Hit error fn!");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This errors b/c the web service is returning...

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">12</string>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is a GET request successful ?

Comment: Get request does not work either.  The other posts I've read mention that it only works with a Post.

Comment: Have you tried Accept: application/json HTTP header?

Comment: Just tried adding the Accept header.  Didn't help.

Comment: Interesting definition of addition...

Answer (score 0):

#### Description

You get the string because you return a string. You should return a object.
The object will get converted to JSon.

#### Sample

```
public class MyClassName 
{
   public string x { get; set }
   public string y { get; set }
}

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public MyClassName Sum()
{
    return new MyClassName { x = "1", y = "2" };
}
```

### Update

You can return a anonymous type too. In this case you don't need the object `MyClassName`

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public MyClassName Sum()
{
    return new { x = "1", y = "2" };
}
```

#### More Information

- [How To Create A JSON Web Service In ASP.NET](http://williamsportwebdeveloper.com/cgi/wp/?p=494)

Comment: This returns    <MyClassName xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<x>1</x>
<y>2</y>
</MyClassName>

Comment: Got this to work locally - thanks.  How about across domains - JSONP?

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE:

Could not get cross domain (jsonp) to work with a Web Service, so switched to an .aspx page and put the logic in Page_Load with a Response.Write().  Works like a charm.

Word of caution for someone just starting to work on something like this, pay attention to the "callback=?" param.  Another word of caution, Flushing and Closing your Response is OK for all browsers except Chrome, for this sends a response to the browser that the stream was closed by the server.  Chrome handles this differently.  Just let it go and you'll be fine.